# python data from excel dot in between letters

Tags: python, string, excel

I have been researching python recently and I'm a total amateur.

I have an easy question but did not know how to find it.

Here is an example

1st column of my Excel file contains 1st letters of names:

John Baker would be JB

I need to put this 'JB' in a database as: J.B. so a dot after each character.
How would I go about doing this?

I know how to import from excel etc. so just explain it as if its a string i want to change.

eg:

```
blabla = "blabla"

code to make b.l.a.b.l.a.
```

Thank you very much in advance,

Aaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
".".join("blabla")
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this. If `bla = "blabla"` is your variable then one way is:

```
'.'.join(bla)+'.'
```

Another One:

```
''.join(map(lambda x:x+'.',bla))
```

Or:

```
''.join(a+'.' for a in bla)
```

Comment: Here is another geek way! `'%s.'%'.'.join(bla)`

Comment: yep, but very similar to the first one.